# emacs shell: change directory with ido

Tags: emacs, elisp

I use the emacs shell-mode more and more, and there's something that I wish could be  improved: the completion when changing directory. I'd love to use `ido` or `projectile-find-dir` for that.

**My workflow**

As of today I do all I can *outside* of emacs' shell, to use the power of emacs as much as possible (visiting files with ido, finding files in project with `projectile`, exploring the tree inside dired,…).

I don't cd that often. When I work in a different project I open up another shell buffer. But when I have to, I really miss ido or the **fasd** shell utility (which works, but without its completion interface which is great with zsh, and which isn't as powerfull as the use of ido could be https://github.com/clvv/fasd).

**How to wire that in elisp ?**

I know we can give a list to `ido-completing-read`;

In the shell, typing `cd ../<TAB>` opens up a new *Completions* buffer. It uses `comint-dynamic-completion`, but how to get that list in an elisp list, not in a buffer ?

- is it possible to wire that completions list into ido ? (or projectile or helm or whatever)
- I would appreciate too if you link me to accurate documentation (there's a lot, it's difficult to know what's useful for me)
- or does a solution exist yet ?

Thanks !

**edit**: here is another nice way to cd to recently visited directories, with the fasd utility and ido completion: https://gitlab.com/emacs-stuff/fasd-shell/blob/master/README.org

See [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277748/use-z-jump-around-in-emacs-to-find-directories/25283275).

ps: eshell doesn't work well with some shell scripts, I'd like to stay in shell-mode.

Comment: In regards to your PS, if you don't have many shell scripts, like i do, i run M-& for async-shell-command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, it is a quick and dirty hack and may fail in some cases but should work generally. Also pardon my elisp

```
(require 'ido)
(require 'cl-lib)
(require 'shell)

(defvar my-dir-selected nil "Flag to indicate that user has selected the directory")

(defun my-filter-cd-input (current-input)
  "Takes current user input for `cd' the a list
    whose car is the 'maximum possible directory path'
    and cdr is remaining string.

    Examples:
    '~/.emacs.d/in => ('~./emacs.d/' 'in')
    '/home/gue' => ('/home/' 'gue')
    '~/../' => ('~/../' '')"
  (let* ((unquoted-input (shell-unquote-argument current-input))
     (components (split-string unquoted-input "/"))
         (directory-parts (butlast components))
         (possible-prefix (car (last components))))
    (list (if (string= possible-prefix "")
              unquoted-input
            (concat (mapconcat 'identity directory-parts "/")
                    (when directory-parts "/")))
          possible-prefix)))

(defun my-complete-directory-name (directory current-input)
  "Prompts user for directories in `directory', `current-input'
    is the string entered by the user till now"
  (let* ((filtered-input (my-filter-cd-input current-input))
         (directory-path (car filtered-input))
         (partial-input (cadr filtered-input))
         (directory-choices (mapcar 'file-name-nondirectory
                                    (condition-case nil
                                        (cl-remove-if-not 'file-directory-p
                                                          (directory-files (concat directory directory-path) t))
                                      ('file-error (list)))))
         (selected-name (ido-completing-read "Directory: "
                                             directory-choices
                                             nil nil partial-input)))
    (comint-delete-input)
    (insert (concat "cd " 
            (shell-quote-argument (concat directory-path selected-name "/"))))))

(defun my-prompt-for-dir-or-fallback ()
  "If current shell command is `cd' prompt for directory
    using ido otherwise fallback to normal completion"
  (interactive)
  (let* ((user-input (buffer-substring-no-properties (comint-line-beginning-position)
                                                     (point-max))))
    (if (and (>= (length user-input) 3)
             (string= (substring user-input 0 3) "cd "))
        (progn 
          (setq my-dir-selected nil)
          (while (not my-dir-selected)
            (my-complete-directory-name default-directory 
                    (buffer-substring-no-properties (+ (comint-line-beginning-position) 3) 
                                    (point-max))))
          (comint-send-input))
      (call-interactively 'completion-at-point))))

(define-key shell-mode-map (kbd "<tab>") 'my-prompt-for-dir-or-fallback)

(add-hook 'ido-setup-hook 'ido-my-keys)

(defun ido-my-keys ()
  "Add my keybindings for ido."
  (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "<C-return>") (lambda ()
                                                        (interactive)
                                                        (setq my-dir-selected t)
                                                        (ido-exit-minibuffer))))
```

Hitting `<tab>` in shell will prompt for directories available using ido if the currently entered command is `cd`, otherwise it will fallback to default completion, to exit press `C-RET`

Comment: Wow, this is absolutely fantastic ! Thanks, and congrats, I will study your elisp carefully. One thing though: do you think it would be possible that after selecting the first directory with RET, ido keeps asking for the following sub-directory ? We could finish the selection with C-j. It would be easier to go more than one dir deep.

Comment: You should keep working on it and make it easily available (ELPA package ?), it's definitely worth it, it is so handy.

Comment: Hi I am glad it helped you. About making ido ask about following subdirectory immediately after user selects a directory, it seems to be tricky to implement, I try and let you know I manage to achieve it

Comment: Hi @Ehvince, sorry for the delay, I have made some changes, now ido will keep asking for subdirectory after selecting directory with RET, to finish selection press `C-RET`.

Comment: This is astonishing. Congrats. You are pardonned for the delay :)

Comment: I found some caveats: it doesn't work with spaces or quotes in path names (yes… I use them sometimes even on unix :p ), and it is annoying because therefore we can't cd into those dirs (except if we escape all them manually). Take your time :)

Comment: Hi @Ehvince, I forgot to quote arguments, it should be better now

Comment: Thanks :) It is now greatly usable. Wish I could upvote again !

Comment: oh, we can not hit C-RET any more :( (it displays some ido help instead) we have to C-g and RET.

Comment: Hi, I am able to user `C-RET` without any issues, one of the reasons I chose `C-RET` was that it did not conflict with any other bindings. Can you check what command `C-RET` is running by doing `C-h k` `C-RET`?

Comment: Oh yes, of course. It was due to `cua-mode` enabled. I disabled it, and it works like a charm :)

Comment: Great, really happy I could help you!

Comment: I added an entry into wikemacs: http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Shell#Change_directory_with_ido-mode

Comment: @Ehvince Oh, that nice.