# Use z (jump around) in Emacs to find directories

Tags: shell, emacs, cd

[Z](https://github.com/rupa/z) is a popular shell tool for jumping around commonly used directories. It uses ["frecency"](https://github.com/rupa/z/wiki/frecency) as a metric for determining which directory you intend to jump to based on keyword completions. So if I commonly cd to `~/.ssh`, I can `z ssh` to jump there.

My question is how can I get the same functionality to work inside Emacs? That is, I want to be able to use `ido-find-file` or something similar but only have to type a few characters to jump to the directory I intended. Hopefully the solution can incorporate `z` itself so it makes use of the frecency metric already recorded by `z`.

Comment: Not exactly the answer to your question, but maybe you should look at [Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles). Summon @Drew.

Comment: @tripleee: Sorry, but Icicles does not really have anything, out of the box, to help with this. It gives you easy access to your recently used files - but not just directories. (It leverages `recentf-list`.) I'm guessing there is something out there that fits the request well, but I'm unaware of it. With [Bookmark+](http://www.emacswiki.org/BookmarkPlus) you can use Dired bookmarks, but bookmark creation is not automatic (you need to hit a key, even for an autonamed bookmark). (Or you can have Emacs file-cache commands automatically create bookmarks - option `bmkp-autofile-filecache`.)

Comment: @tripleee: Well, I take back the part of bookmarking never being automatic. [This section](http://www.emacswiki.org/BookmarkPlus#AutomaticBookmarking) of the Bookmark+ doc describes an automatic bookmarking feature. Whether that is something that might be useful here, I can't say.

Comment: @tripleee: A last comment: it would be easy to add the possibility to use a predicate to control automatic bookmarking (e.g., bookmarks could be created automatically only in Dired buffers or whenever the moon is full or whatever). Currently the only parameters governing automatic creation are (a) idle timing and (b) distance from other automatic bookmarks.

Comment: hello there, did you find a solution that works well for you ?

Comment: @Ehvince, yes I went with your suggestion and tried out `fasd`. I've been using it since you posted your answer and I can confirm it works well. Thanks!

Comment: Cool. And even cooler, I edited my answer with a better code: ido completion is triggered by the TAB key when the shell prompt begins with `d ` (d and space), just like in a real shell. And we have even better completion than zsh !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used z once but then I found [fasd](https://github.com/clvv/fasd), which is inspired by autojump, z or v, and which I found much more powerful, if I remember well it is because:

- it not only finds directories but also files
- it can `cd` a result or use `mplayer` or your editor or another command
- the completion is better, specially for zsh (again, if I remember well). The thing is, I constantly use the `d` alias to change directories.

Anyway, there's an emacs package to find files with it: https://github.com/steckerhalter/emacs-fasd
That's cool, but it isn't as interactive as I would like.

edit: then I had to update the package and:

```
(setq fasd-enable-initial-prompt nil)  ;; don't ask for first query but fire fuzzy completion straight away.
```

There's a still a use case that isn't filled:

### How  to use fasd (or autojump or z) with completion in an emacs shell ?

I often use emacs' shell-mode. When I use my favorite alias `d`, it works, but I don't have completion at all. Here, zsh's completion is clearly missing. So I would like to use ido completion, for instance. I wrote a little function which you can easily adapt for z:

**edit**: finished the command and added ido completion triggered by TAB. Now type `d` (d followed by a space). If it keeps changing and if I manage to create a minor mode I'll post the link to my gitlab repo.

**edit**: I created a mode for this feature: https://gitlab.com/emacs-stuff/fasd-shell/tree/master

```
    ;; Use the fasd command line utility to change recently visited directories and more.

(defun fasd-get-path-list (pattern)
  "call fasd with pattern and return the list of possibilities"
  (s-split "\n" (s-trim (shell-command-to-string (format "fasd -l -R %s" pattern))))
)

(defun fasd ()
  "If current shell command is `d something' call fasd"
  (interactive)
  (let* ((user-input (buffer-substring-no-properties (comint-line-beginning-position)
                                                     (point-max))))
    (if (and (string= (substring user-input 0 2) "d "))  ;; todo: mapping to use something else than d and change directory.
        (progn
          ;; get what is after "d "
          (setq fasd-pattern (buffer-substring-no-properties (+ (comint-line-beginning-position) 2) (point-max)))
          (setq fasd-command (concat "cd " (ido-completing-read "cd to: " (fasd-get-path-list fasd-pattern))))
          (comint-kill-input)
          (insert fasd-command)
          (comint-send-input)
          ))))

;; Use TAB as in normal shell. Now we have even better completion than in zsh !
(define-key shell-mode-map (kbd "<tab>") 'fasd)  ;; works like a charm :)
```

As a side note, I don't use it very often because I open shells in the directory of the current buffer with [shell-here](https://github.com/ieure/shell-here) and [shell-pop](https://github.com/kyagi/shell-pop-el) (a drop-down terminal like guake for gnome).

Comment: See my second edit: I created a minor mode for this feature. https://gitlab.com/emacs-stuff/fasd-shell/tree/master

Answer (score 1):

Within a project, I find `projectile` ([Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile)) mode to be really helpful.

I use the standard keybindings `C-p f` or `M-x projectile-find-file`.

It does fuzzy matching on filenames and filters on recently used files.

Comment: I use `helm-ls-git-ls` to find files within a project. What I need is a quick way to jump to the project directory.

Comment: you may interested by projectile's helm interface to switch projects where several actions are defined, one of them being to open dired in project's directory. It's a coming feature: https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/commit/639383a22cafbd6b79135b342a2b15a44c7d36f5